# Why doesn't Grails notify me of error at domain object saving?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm just starting with Grails, and here is the first issue.

I spent several hours to find out that domain object cannot be inserted in DB, until all its properties are populated.

```
class Item {
  String title
  String link
}

class ItemController {
  def fetch = {
    def item = new Item()
    item.title = "blabla"
    // no value for "link"
    item.save()
  }
}
```

Looks logical, but why is it skipped so silently? Can I configure something to get exceptions in such cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No exception is thrown by default .

The `save()` method injected to Domain classes returns `false` if an error has occured during the validation phase.
A classic code sample for checking save/update of a domain class is :

```
if (!myDomainObj.save()) {
   log.warn myDomainObj.errors.allErrors.join(' \n') //each error is an instance of  org.springframework.validation.FieldError    
}
```

If you need to have an exception for a particular domain class, use:

```
myDomainObj.save(failOnError: true)
```

and exceptions for validation failures will be thrown.

If you want to throw an exception for EVERY domain classes, then simply set `grails.gorm.failOnError` to `true` in *grails-app/conf/Config.groovy*

Be carefull : all domain properties have an implicit `nullable: false` constraint.

I recommend you reading [this article](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/).

Comment: Thank you for `grails.gorm.failOnError = true`. IMHO it should be the default. In any case it's a perfect complement to this one that I like to use: `grails.gorm.default.constraints = { '*' nullable: true }` The constraints block should be used to **add** constraints, such as some field being required, not to lift them.

Comment: Ideally, IMHO, Grails should make `belongsTo` fields required by default, and all others optional.

Answer (score 4):

To make your `save()` call throw a `RuntimeException`, you can use `item.save(failOnError:true)` . But you can also check the return value of save() method. If it's false, that means something wrong happened.

```
if (item.save()) {
   //succeeded
}
else  {
   //not succeeded
}
```

Comment: aha, it returns id. I thought null means nothing here. Thanks!